# How to add new rows to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a users table like this:

```
INSERT INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender)
VALUES
(1, 'sample1@sample1.com', 'johnd', 'john', 'doe', '0000-00-00', 'Male'),
(2, 'sample1@sample2.com', 'marryb', 'marry', 'brown', '0000-00-00', 'Female');
```

I prepared a new user list on notepad like below:

> (3, 'sample3@sample3.com', 'alij', 'ali', 'johnson', '0000-00-00', 'Male'),
>   (4, 'sample4@sample4.com', 'janew', 'jane', 'white', '0000-00-00', 'Female');

How can I add the new users to my database using a SQL command?

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: What's your issue here? What happens when you run an `INSERT` command like the first one with the new values?

Comment: No error. I have poor knowledge about SQL commands. I use a ready php script and wanted to learn how can I add new data without using admin panel. I'm happy to learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (1, 'sample1@sample1.com', 'johnd', 'john', 'doe', '0000-00-00', 'Male');
INSERT INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (3, 'sample1@sample2.com', 'marryb', 'marry', 'brown', '0000-00-00', 'Female');
INSERT INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (4, 'sample3@sample3.com', 'alij', 'ali', 'johnson', '0000-00-00', 'Male');
INSERT INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (5, 'sample4@sample4.com', 'janew', 'jane', 'white', '0000-00-00', 'Female');
```

Or just simply `INSERT ALL INTO`

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (1, 'sample1@sample1.com', 'johnd', 'john', 'doe', '0000-00-00', 'Male')
  INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (3, 'sample1@sample2.com', 'marryb', 'marry', 'brown', '0000-00-00', 'Female')
  INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (4, 'sample3@sample3.com', 'alij', 'ali', 'johnson', '0000-00-00', 'Male')
  INTO signup (UID, email, username, fname, lname, bdate, gender,) VALUES (5, 'sample4@sample4.com', 'janew', 'jane', 'white', '0000-00-00', 'Female')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own question. That SQL is an INSERT statement, not the table. It is used to INSERT data into a table. So you need to create the table 'signup' if it does not already exist. Then you just use your insert with the additional sets of data in your brackets.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html